# how to configure root folder for jquery file tree?

Tags: jquery, jsp, web-applications, jquery-plugins, filetree

I used the following code for configuring my jquery file tree.

```
    <script>
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#loadFolderTree').fileTree({
                    root: '/',
                    script: 'assets/plugins/jquery_file_tree/connectors/jqueryFileTree.jsp',
                    multiFolder: false
                }, function (file) {
                    alert(file);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Its working fine, the script is loading up, the only problem I face is, I am not getting the root folder of my web-application. Instead, it is giving me this (I cant upload image, so here is how my file-tree looks):

- Agent
- bin
- Boot
- c:
- C:
- css
- database-dump
- dev
- etc
- F:
- home
- images
- js
- Kart
- lib
- lib64
- logs
- lost+found
- media
- META-INF
- mnt
  (List of directories go on and on)

I have absolutely no idea how to set path to my web-application root folder. How can I guide it to my actual web-application server folder?

Answer (score 0):

"/" is the absolute root path of file system. You might try with "." for getting current folder of web-application.

Comment: I tried it. It opened some other folder. Any other solution I should go for?

Answer (score -1):

You might also want to try looking at your css, and making sure it's set.

Comment: Please avoid commenting in answer section.